# Is it possible to build a package with bitbake without poky?

Tags: package, packaging, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I have all compiled binaries for target machine. I want to create a binary package - say `.ipk`, `.rpm` -  for target machine. As [this](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0.1/mega-manual/mega-manual.html) suggested to clone `poky`, which will have `bitbake` within it. But, as [this](http://hambedded.org/blog/2012/11/24/from-bitbake-hello-world-to-an-image/) document says, we can directly use `bitbake` without `poky`, however, it not mentioned anywhere that we need `poky` as well as `bitbake` to build a custom package. But of course `poky` is required if we have to compile source code and create binaries.

If I don't need to compile any source code at all, does I need to have `Poky`?

Is it possible to build a package with only `bitbake`?

Answer (score 1):

First, Poky is a reference distribution that contains primarily bitbake and openembedded-core.

Yes, you need oe-core to build packages as the logic to build packages is part of oe-core, not bitbake.

Comment: thanks! I have compiled binaries, so no compilation required, I don't want to create `image`, in simple steps can you tell me how can I build a package with these binaries?

Comment: Write a recipe to package the binaries.  The bin_package class is helpful here.

I worry that when you say "I don't want to create an image" that you mean you're trying to use bitbake to build a single package for Fedora or Debian.  If this is the case then bitbake is far more than you need.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this class. I am trying to build the package for `Yocto Project 1.6` which codename is `Diasy`, `poky` version `11`, and arch `p2020`.